# C# get specific variable of list

Tags: c#

I created the list

```
List<Worker> list = new List<Worker>();
```

In the class "Worker" are 2 variables:

```
public static int ID = 0;
public string Name;
```

When i create the list, i want to output only the name of each worker, so i created a for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Worker {i+1}: {//name of worker}");
        }
```

but i don`t know how to extract the variable "Name" from the list

Comment: you can also write a toString method

Comment: @Thecave3 why? This isn't Java and the question wasn't how to generate strings. It was how to access an element in a list

Comment: Why do you have a `static` ID?

Comment: Lists can be indexed just like arrays, eg `temp[i]` will return the i-th element.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos C# has a to string method too that could be overridden. Its signature is 'public override string ToString()' if you're modeling a class properly. It may be out of the contest my comment and it's ok, but please don't associate "ToString" or every element of software design to Java.

Answer (score 3):

Well as the Worker has a `Name` property, then you can access it as simple as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Worker {i+1}: {temp[i].Name}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When *querying* (in your case you want `index` and `Name`) try using *Linq* which has been designed for querying:

```
  // When querying you can easily add conditions - Where, order - OrderBy etc.
  var query = list 
    .Select((worker, i) => $"Worker {i + 1}: {worker.Name}");
```

Then you can easily print it out:

```
 foreach (item in query)
     Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Or even

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, query));
```